# Complex rails validation for associated object related attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two objects Booking and Coupon

I want to associate the coupon with booking on the base of below validations

the problem with below code is that the syntax is incorrect and second that I cannot use the symbol styled syntax (:) operator to access internal values of second object

```
with_options if: :coupon?, unless: coupon.future_useable? do |booking|
  validates :start_time_minutes, numericality: {
    greater_than_equal_to: coupon.start_time_minutes }
  validates :finish_time_minutes, numericality: {
    less_than_equal_to: coupon.finish_time_minutes }
end
```

what would be the best approach in writing the above code

Comment: Bit too much code to read here based on your question. You need to be more specific on where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with_options if: :coupon?, unless: 'coupon.future_useable?' do
  validates :start_time_minutes, numericality: {
    greater_than_equal_to: -> { coupon.start_time_minutes} }

  validates :finish_time_minutes, numericality: {
    less_than_equal_to: -> { coupon.finish_time_minutes } }
end
```